# apache 2.4 custom error responses

Tags: apache

After upgrading from apache 2.2 to 2.4, when running apachectl configtest I am getting following error

```
Syntax error on line 36 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf:
Unsupported HTTP response code 509

Line 36 of my /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf:
ErrorDocument 509 "The page you are requesting cannot be served."
```

Any Ideas how to resolve this one.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code 509 was [removed/nullified](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blame/2.4.x/modules/http/http_protocol.c#L179) from Apache 2.4 due to it's not being defined in the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Status Code Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) as discussed [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-665). Apache will fail to load when an ErrorDocument is defined with an invalid status code.

To resolve your particular configuration error you will want to change the ErrorDocument definition to use a supported status code instead of 509. Find one most relevant to your particular use case. You can reference a list of valid status codes [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__HTTP__Status.html).